# JFreeChart bar chart category axis offset

Tags: java, bar-chart, jfreechart

I'm using `JFreeChart` to generate a bar chart, which is working fine. Dataset contains multiple values but if dataset contains only one value bar is getting 
displayed in middle instead of bottom:

[image]

I need it to display like following:

[image: Bar Chart Image to be]

Following is the code that I am using to generate the bar chart:

```
double max = 200;
// Prepare the data set
DefaultCategoryDataset barDataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
barDataset.setValue(225, "Billed", "Dec");
//Create the chart
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
    "", "", "", barDataset,
    PlotOrientation.HORIZONTAL, false, true, false);
ChartPanel chart3 = new ChartPanel(chart);
chart3.getChart().getPlot().setOutlinePaint(null);
(chart3.getChart().getPlot()).setBackgroundAlpha(0.0f); // setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);;
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setRange(0, max);
if (max <= 10) {
    rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(2));
    System.out.println("tick unit 2 max " + max);
} else {
    rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(5 * (Math.ceil(Math.abs((max / 6) / 5)))));
    System.out.println("tick unit " + (5 * (Math.ceil(Math.abs((max / 6) / 5)))) + " max " + max);
}
Font font3 = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.BOLD, 22);
plot.getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(font3);
plot.getRangeAxis().setLabelFont(font3);
plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryMargin(0.3);
Font categoryLabelFont = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.BOLD, 12);
CategoryAxis categoryAxis = (CategoryAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
categoryAxis.setTickLabelFont(categoryLabelFont);
ValueAxis valueAxis = (ValueAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
valueAxis.setTickLabelFont(categoryLabelFont);
plot.setRangeGridlinesVisible(true);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(new Color(192, 192, 192));
plot.setRangeGridlineStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBarPainter(new StandardBarPainter());
// ajust the bar width and spacing between bars
renderer.setMaximumBarWidth(0.1);
// Spaces between bars
renderer.setItemMargin(0.1);
plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
// custom columns color
renderer.setSeriesPaint(0, new Color(0xf5, 0x8a, 0x86));
renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, new Color(0xf0, 0x56, 0x60));
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(new File(imagePath), chart, 510, 260);
```

Comment: Your images are identical. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.